# primeng chart round axis labels

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I am trying to draw a Line chart with PrimeNg 
the axis and the ayis are huge (2051 element), I want to round the labels 
this a capture of the chart 
[image]

Comment: Use the Math methods as in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)